# Scaling MS Business Central between servers

Tags: dynamics-business-central

I have a question about Service Layer(SL):
can I build cluster with several SL servers to load scaling?

Where can I read about it?

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can create all the servesr with any number of server instances (service layers) you want - all running on the same database. That will work just fine.

However there is no built-in load balancing so you would have to handle that on your own.

The most common way of doing this is simply by providing different shortcuts to different groups of users. Each shortcut is linked to their own server instance and thus the users are directed to different servers.